# Sql join notation: Is this equivalent to inner or full join?

Tags: sql, syntax

```
 select  a.somefield, b.someotherfield
 from    a, b
 where   a.key = b.key
```

Is the above equivalent to:

```
 select  a.somefield, b.someotherfield
 from    a join b on a.key = b.key
```

or:

```
 select  a.somefield, b.someotherfield
 from    a full join b on a.key = b.key
```

I am pretty sure it's equivalent to an inner join but just realized I'd never really thought about it before.  Also I'm wondering if there are any edge cases where it is not 100% equivalent?

Comment: It's equivalent to an inner join (I believe in 100% of cases).  The wikipedia article on joins clearly states that these are equivalent by the way :).

Comment: @Corbin Yep, 100% of the time.  I had thought there could be different behaviour if the ANSI_NULLS setting is OFF.  I mistakenly thought ANSI_NULLS didn't affect joins, but it just doesn't affect column to column comparisons (regardless of whether they are in where or join expressions)

Comment: In no context is null = null guaranteed to be true.  Whether a join clause or a where clause, IS NULL always has to be used.

Comment: @Corbin If ANSI_NULLS is off, then null = null is guaranteed to be true *IF* you are not comparing separate columns.  In a future version of SQL Server, setting ANSI_NULLS off may cause an exception but that's not the case yet.

Comment: Interesting...  Haven't dealt with MSSQL in about 4 years.  Although a flag to disable standard behavior is kind of... bleh.  I guess that's why it will eventually throw an exception though.

Comment: @Corbin It's not 'supposed' to serve the purpose of disabling standard behavior for convenience sake.  It's only supposed to be there so legacy code won't break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original notion is equivalent to an inner join.

Using the "where" syntax, there is no standard equivalent for any of the outer joins (left outer join, right outer join, full outer join).  Oracle supports a "+" syntax, to represent the left and right outer joins.

In addition, leaving out the condition in the where clause is equivalent to a cross join.

However, you should get used to using the join syntax in the from clause.  Once you get used to it, it is much clearer about the intentions of the query and much less prone to error.

Comment: Ha, don't worry I know how to write joins.  I'm rewriting a system and as I'm going through what the original code did I just want to make sure I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: I do know SQL Server had a star notation to represent left/right joins but it may be deprecated by now.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Just to emphasize Gordon's point (in case you are waiting for a *different* answer), you cannot use the `WHERE` syntax to make an equivalent of an outer join, and `FULL JOIN` *is* an outer join. So there you are, your first snippet isn't an equivalent of `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: @AndriyM Up until I did a few tests a second ago I could have sworn there was an edge case.  I finally remembered what I thought it was:  the difference in behaviour when ANSI_NULLS is on or off.  I *thought* that this setting didn't affect joins.  But really, it affects join conditions the same way:  it turns out it just doesn't affect column to column comparisons regardless of whether it's in a where or join condition.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: I hardly ever remember about that setting, because I've never used it in the projects I've worked with, nor ever needed to. As a result, I know very little about its effects in various situations. I mean, I *could*, of course, just work out some, if not all, of them based on the knowledge of what the setting essentially changes, but nothing can replace a good, thorough experiment. So thank you for coming back and sharing the results of your tests!

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, I definitely don't recommend setting ANSI_NULLS off becauase it just makes things confusing :)  But a couple years ago I worked for a POS company whose product was over 10+ years old and the owner had hired several unqualified programmers to work on it over the years.  (I actually never even gave him a Resume before getting hired!)