# selecting LIKE value IN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

I have 2 tables

**atm_name_initials (initial)**

```
KS
FW
GE
SD
```

**atm_tasks_dit (task_name,task_given_to)**

```
task1 KS
task2 GE
task3 GE/SD
```

Now i want to `SELECT` all distinct names from `atm_name_initials` `WHERE` they are founded `IN LIKE atm_tasks_dit.task_given_to`

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT initial FROM atm_name_initials
WHERE initial 
IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT task_given_to FROM atm_tasks_dit
    WHERE on_big_project_id = 29
)
```

What this piece of code does it searches if EXACLY the `atm_name_initials.initial` value is founded in `atm_tasks_dit.task_given_to`

i would like something like

```
SELECT initial FROM atm_name_initials
WHERE initial 
"IS LIKE" IN

'%
(
    SELECT DISTINCT task_given_to FROM atm_tasks_dit
    WHERE on_big_project_id = 29
)
%'
```

or something...

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: in atm_name_initials there are no duplicates, but in atm_tasks_dit might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mix between answers proposed, using MySQL sintax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT initial
  FROM atm_tasks_dit,atm_name_initials
 WHERE task_given_to LIKE CONCAT('%',initial,'%')
```

Just in case check [SQL Fiddle code](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eec3/19).

And here is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420554/use-like-with-field-values-in-mysql).

Comment: hey, thank you it works! but in that example i see a INNER JOIN, and what type of select is this? SELECT FROM table1,table2 ... is like a union,join?? what is it?

Comment: You are welcome. This is equivalent to a `INNER JOIN`. Check this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694527/sql-join-notation-is-this-equivalent-to-inner-or-full-join) for more details.

Comment: ok, this is a inner join, ok? so this translates as http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eec3/22 ? because it's more readable and logical

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I usually use the `JOIN` but this time I used this other way of doing in it ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT initial 
FROM   atm_name_initials
join   atm_tasks_dit
on     initial like concat('%',task_given_to,'%')
WHERE  on_big_project_id = 29
```

Comment: ok, but this is MySQL, i have to find a method to concat this?

Comment: the idea is that i have to find everyone that had worked in that project, not just flush all the name initials

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select distinct ani.initial--atd.task_name,atd.task_given_to
From atm_tasks_dit atd
join atm_name_initials ani on atd.task_given_to like '%' + ani.initial + '%'
-- WHERE on_big_project_id = 29
```

**Result**

*initial*

```
GE 
KS 
SD
```

I did in Sql Server as I don't have MySql install

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i'm using mysql